# execute system commands which need input using PHP

Tags: php, pear, pecl

Is there a way in PHP to make `exec()` or one of its variants run a system command that needs user input in the execution session. Can be an `FTP transfer` for example or even just a print statement command with `more` flag. Say for e.g. in `Windows command prompt` I do a `type bigfile.txt | more` It gives me one screen of output and then I use the keyboard to have the next line come up.

Is there a way to capture this behavior using any of the PHP command line execution functions, when running from the browser?  If not in standard PHP are there any `PEAR`/`PECL` resources which anyone has used before which does this?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do this with [proc_open](http://php.net/proc_open), which can be used in a non-blocking manner, and gives you input and output pipes.

However, as a rule of thumb, I'd only attempt this as a last resort.  Using a non-interactive executable, or a native PHP library will usually be far more maintainable.  For example, I'm struggling to come up with a reason you'd ever want to `proc_open('mycommand | more')` when you can just `exec('mycommand')`